# Web API Odata - how to query on ComplexType?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, wcf-data-services, odata

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web-Api service that supports OData.

The main components of the service are

the Model:

```
namespace OdataServiceTest.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public EnumType Gender { get; set; } // Complex Type
    }

    public class EnumType
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Key { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the Controller:

```
public class PersonsController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/Persons
        [Queryable]
        public IQueryable<Person> Get()
        {
            Person[] person = new Person[] {
            new Person() { Name="Ronen", Age=23, Gender=new EnumType() { Key=1,Value="Male" } }
            };
            return person.AsQueryable();
        }
}
```

An empty query returns the following results

```
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Person>
<Name>Ronen</Name>
<Age>23</Age>
<BirthDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</BirthDate>
<Gender Key="1">Male</Gender>
</Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

I want the query on the gender field, which is a complex type, to look like:

```
http://localhost:7116/api/Persons?$filter=Gender eq 1
```

How do I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this query instead.

```
http://localhost:7116/api/Persons?$filter=Gender/Key eq 1
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. It worked but i don't want to make changes to my query.I thought maybe there is a way to decorate my model with some attributes that'll do the job. Or alternatively, create some mapping between the EnumType to int, but i can't figure how to do it.